# Bootstrap modal nested further than top level HTML

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm building a sandbox app in Angular and I want to use a modal in a component nested within a component.

The modal toggles on just fine, but it sits behind it's own backdrop - which is understandable. The docs recommend to use it as 'top level' in the HTML as possible, but is there any way to use custom CSS to force the functionality of the modal?

Thus far I've tried:

```
.modal {
    z-index: 1701 !important;
}

.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1700 !important;
}

.modal.show .modal-dialog {
    z-index: 1702 !important;
}
```

And I can see that they are the rules being applied in the dev tools, but it still appears behind the backdrop and other components higher up in the DOM tree.

Comment: Problem likely is your backdrop isn't in the same stacking context as the dialog, so z-index doesn't help. If you want to declare the template in some child component you'd need a way to pass a templateref to someone to be rendered in the root level. Have you tried https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap ? Has a very easy to use modal service which does this for you.

Comment: And an alternative to ngx-bootstrap is [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples). :-)

Comment: @funkizer that definitely sounds right. My issue is that if the `modal` template is outside of my angular `component` I have to fiddle around with `@Inputs and @Outputs` since I have data entry going on in the modal. I'm just hoping for a way I can do direct 2 way binding to my modal... I'll check out that git link however!

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be better if you shared more code here (are there additional classes here? How did you instantiate the modal?)

Either way, check out this example:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/13/angularjs-custom-modal-example-tutorial
Should be relatively easy :)